# Is there a Debian package for Emacs that contains the source (.el files) v. the compiled code (.elc)?

Tags: debian, emacs

In my old versions of Ubuntu I would automatically get the dot-el files for emacs when I installed it. This was very useful because if I wanted a private version of a function (eg compile-without-questions automatically saves all files before running the compile function) I could consult the source of the official version and amend it.

My work-place used Red Hat and I was able to add to the specification of new machines that some package was installed that contained the dot-el files (the source code versus the compiled code) but I can't remember what it was.

My home machine is Debian-based (Mint) and I'm looking for a similar Debian package but failing. Is there one?

I know I could install Emacs from source for myself and get them that way but that seems overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re looking for `emacs24-el`, `emacs25-el`, or `emacs-el`, depending on the version of Emacs you have (`emacs-el` is for Emacs 26).

Comment: spot on, thank you. There was no emacs-el so I had to work out which version of emacs I was running (25) and install emacs25-el

Answer (score 1):

In my debian system there is a package named `emacs24-el` with the sources.

Comment: Thank you, I needed emacs25-el but that hint would have given me the correct answer